# How to define a new name prefix in biblatex-mla?

Tags: biblatex, citing, mla-style

I need to cite an author whose last name is d'Ardenne, and I want it to sort under A as it would if the name were de Ardenne. However, `biblatex-mla` does not seem to recognize "d'" as a prefix and sorts it under "d," putting it at the end of the bibliography because the "d" is lowercase:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,useprefix=true,style=mla]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{dardenne,
  author =    {d'Ardenne, S.R.T.O.},
  title =     {Title},
  year      = {1961},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {address}
}

@book{tolkien,
  author =    {Tolkien, J.R.R.},
  title =     {Title},
  year      = {1929},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {address}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I figure the easiest way to fix this is to define a new name prefix "d'", but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `sortname` field. However, it's better to use `backend=biber` and `biber` for compiling the bibliography, instead of `bibtex8`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,useprefix=true,style=mla]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{dardenne,
  author =    {d'Ardenne, S.R.T.O.},
  sortname =  {Ardenne},
  title =     {Title},
  year      = {1961},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {address}
}

@book{bolkien,
  author =    {Bolkien, J.R.R.},
  title =     {Title},
  year      = {1929},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {address}
}

@book{tolkien,
  author =    {Tolkien, J.R.R.},
  title =     {Title},
  year      = {1929},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  address   = {address}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's a great solution and it works perfectly. I'll be sure to use `biber` from here on out as well. Thanks again!